# Video Embed in FieldFormatter

Tags: 8, nodes, entities

I want to embed the video as follows. I have written a FieldFormatter for this.

```
public function viewElements(FieldItemListInterface $items, $langcode) {
    $element = [];

    foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
      // Render each element as markup.
        $target_id = $item->getValue()['target_id'];

        $file = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($target_id); //load the file and its attribute.        
        $parts = pathinfo($file->getFileUri());
        $new_filename = $parts['filename'] . '_' . $file->getCreatedTime() .'_selfhelpvideofid_' . $target_id . '.' . $parts['extension'];            

        $video = '<video width="480" height="320" controls="controls">
                    <source src="movie.mp4"  type="video/mp4">
                  </video>';    

      $element[$delta] = [
        '#type' => 'markup',
        '#markup' => $video,
      ];
    }

    return $element;
  }
```

The above is not working. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of #markup, which is filtered, use inline template:

```
$file_path = 'movie.mp4'

$video = '<video width="480" height="320" controls="controls">
  <source src="{{ file_path }}"  type="video/mp4">
</video>';

$element[$delta] = array(
  '#type' => 'inline_template',
  '#template' => $video,
  '#context' => array(
    'file_path' => $file_path,
  ),
);
```